# Write full ref name

Tags: ref

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Paint }
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics{22.png}
    \label{fig:22}
\end{figure}

This is example reference \autoref{fig:22}
```

It write

```
This is example reference Figure 1
```

instead

```
This is example reference Paint 1.
```

What should I do to get Paint 1?

Comment: As always on this site, plesae provide a full (but minimal) example instead of a sniplet like this. Since `\ref` normally does not give any `Figure` prefix, you have something in your document you're not showing us.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's `\autoref`

Comment: Again, update your question, not everyone know where `\autoref` is coming from. It is a lot easier to help if one can just copy the code and try it as is. For example, use `\rule{5cm}{5cm}` instead of your image, then that requirement in the example is gone too.\

Comment: it's enough code to see problem. I'd like to see "Paint 1", instead default "1" or "Figure 1"

Comment: If you don't use the `babel` package then `\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Paint}` works. If you do use `babel` then you need `\addtoextrasnameofyourlanguage{\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Paint}}` as explained in for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186946/changing-the-autoref-name-for-chapter. You didn't provide a full example so it's hard to tell which of the two you need, or maybe even another option depending on your setup. Note that you should not put a space character after `Paint ` because there is already a space inserted automatically.

Comment: Actually I'd say it is very selfish to not provide code others can test without adding a lot of stuff. Potentially their solution might then be wrong because you're using some package you never mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Just create  a new environment for paintings.

It would just be easier to create your own new environment than tinkering with figure. Combining the solutions from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57055/106804) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408126/106804) you can easily create a new environment for paintings that behaves just like figures would, but built for purpose:

## Output

[image]

## MWE

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
fileext=lop,
listname={List of Paintings},
name=Painting,
placement=tbhp,
within=section,
]{painting}

\crefname{painting}{painting}{paintings}
\Crefname{painting}{Painting}{Paintings}


\begin{document}
\begin{painting}
\centering
Some painting should go here.
\caption{Something about the painting.}
\label{painting}
\end{painting}

You could use \texttt{autoref} to reference \autoref{painting}, but likely \texttt{cref} would be better to refer to \cref{painting} as either \Cref{painting} or \cref{painting}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your `figure` environment should be labeled “Paint” (but you should check the grammar), you can do it with `hyperref` only.

However you *need* the caption, or the `\label` will refer to something random.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Paint} % is it right?
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Paint}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}

\caption{A caption}\label{fig:22}
\end{figure}

This is example reference \autoref{fig:22}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `cleveref`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Paint} % is it right?
\crefname{figure}{Paint}{Paints}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}

\caption{A caption}\label{fig:22}
\end{figure}

This is example reference \cref{fig:22}

\end{document}
```